# Svn analog of git-shell

Tags: ssh, git, svn

I have configured git,so I can pull/push via ssh, authorization via public key, 
but if I try to make direct shell access, I get

```
Last login: Mon Aug 13 20:12:20 2012 from 192.168.1.3
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
Connection to inferno closed.
```

Is it analog of `git-shell` for svn? Or, what should I do to make svn public key authorization without granting shell access?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish? You can go years in git without using `git shell` directly.

Comment: @christopher svn public key authorization without granting shell access

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/123501/how-can-i-allow-a-linux-subversion-user-to-only-execute-svnserve